# 'advanced(by:)' is unavailable convert from swift 3 to swift 4

Tags: xcode, swift3, swift4

```
 internal func rangeFromNSRange(_ nsRange: NSRange) -> Range<String.Index>? {
    let from16 = utf16.startIndex.advanced(by: nsRange.location)
    let to16 = from16.advanced(by: nsRange.length) //advanced(by:) is unavailable
    if let from = String.Index(from16, within: self),
        let to = String.Index(to16, within: self) {
        return from ..< to
    }
    return nil
}
```

I have this file in swift 3 and I'm trying to convert it to swift 4 but I get this error and also this error

```
  public func height(_ width: CGFloat, font: UIFont, lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakMode?) -> CGFloat {
        var attrib: [String: AnyObject] = [NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: font]
        if lineBreakMode != nil {
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode!
            attrib.updateValue(paragraphStyle, forKey: NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle.rawValue)
        }
        let size = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        return ceil((self as NSString).boundingRect(with: size, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes:attrib, context: nil).height)
    }
```

> // Cannot convert value of type '[String : AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]?'

Comment: What is `attrib` you're seeing as `boundingRect` parameter?

Comment: can you check my question again please

Comment: Remove `rawValue`. So your `attrib` variable should be `[.font : font]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In Swift 4 there is an API to make `Range<String.Index>` from `NSRange` and vice versa. The `String` extension can be reduced to

   ```
   internal func range(from nsRange: NSRange) -> Range<String.Index>? {
      return Range(nsRange, in: self)
   }
   ```
2. In Swift 4 the type of string attributes has been changed from `String` to `NSAttributedStringKey`. For example `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` is replaced with `NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor`. You need to change the declaration of `attrib` to

   ```
   var attrib: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [.font: font]
   ```

   and to change the line to add an attribute accordingly.